# Delete Avatar from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a destroy action for my user profile picture. The destroy action works properly and the photo is deleted. I can add another picture without any problem, but when I try to delete the picture again I receive the following error message:

Couldn't find Avatar with 'id'=1

This is what is stored in my database Avatar.all reads:

```
[#<Avatar id: 2, avatarpic: "cat_astronaut.jpg", user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-12-05 17:02:08", updated_at: "2017-12-05 17:02:08">]
```

The id is at 2 and not 1, even though I successfully deleted the first  picture with an id of 1. Every time I delete a picture and upload a new one, the id is incremented. So when I try to delete the second uploaded picture, it can't find the right id.  I need the id to be reset to 1 every time I delete the picture.

Controller is as follows:

```
class AvatarsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @avatar = Avatar.new(avatar_params)
    @avatar.user = @user
    @avatar.save
    # Three lines above can be replaced with 
    # @user.create_avatar(params)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @avatar = Avatar.find(params[:id])
  @avatar.user = @user
  @avatar.destroy
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
end

private

def avatar_params
  params.require(:avatar).permit(:avatarpic)
end

end
```

There is only 1 photo according to my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :places
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :avatar, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Code for User's view profile page:

```
<%= link_to user_avatar_path(@user), :title => "Upload New Photo", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to change your Photo?' } do %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
<% end %>
```

rake routes:

```
root GET    /                                     places#index
          place_comments POST   /places/:place_id/comments(.:format)  comments#create
            place_photos POST   /places/:place_id/photos(.:format)    photos#create
                  places GET    /places(.:format)                     places#index
                         POST   /places(.:format)                     places#create
               new_place GET    /places/new(.:format)                 places#new
              edit_place GET    /places/:id/edit(.:format)            places#edit
                   place GET    /places/:id(.:format)                 places#show
                         PATCH  /places/:id(.:format)                 places#update
                         PUT    /places/:id(.:format)                 places#update
                         DELETE /places/:id(.:format)                 places#destroy
            user_avatars POST   /users/:user_id/avatars(.:format)     avatars#create
             user_avatar DELETE /users/:user_id/avatars/:id(.:format) avatars#destroy
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                  users#show
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'places#index'
  resources :places do
    resources :comments, only: :create
    resources :photos, only: :create
  end
  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    resources :avatars, only: [:create]
    resources :avatars, only: [:destroy]
    # or resources :avatars, only: [:create, :destroy]
end 
end
```

Avatar Model:

```
class Avatar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatarpic, AvatarUploader
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code providing the link to your `destroy` action please? It looks as if this is passing the wrong `id` to the `params`, but I'm not sure without seeing that :) Edit: also, the relevant content of `routes.rb` would help out.

Comment: @SRack information updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `link_to` is missing the `avatar_id`. Change

```
user_avatar_path(@user)
```

To

```
user_avatar_path(@user, @user.avatar)
```

Comment: Yes sir this works.  I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: rails console Avatar.all displays:
[#<Avatar id: 5, avatarpic: "cat_astronaut.jpg", user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-12-05 19:32:51", updated_at: "2017-12-05 19:32:51">]

The Avatar id is still incrementing even though I delete the avatar.  The page is displaying properly at least.  No error messages.

Comment: Yes, IDs are never re-used even if you delete the object. New objects always get a new ID

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you so much!